# Page not found (404) No post found matching the query

Tags: python, django

I am working with Django and I am just a beginner.
I am following this [tutorial](https://www.ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/django-beginners-guide) to create a contact form.
But I have this error when I want to go to this URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe8c9.png)

I have 3 apps in my project(Posts, Users and Contact):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'Posts',
'Users',
'crispy_forms',
'Contact',
```

And here is the `urls.py` in my project :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('' , include('Posts.urls')),
   path('',include('Contact.urls')),
]
```

And it is `urls.py` in my `Contact` app:

```
from django.urls import path
from Contact import views


app_name = "Contact"

urlpatterns = [
   path('contact/', views.context, name="contact"),
]
```

And this is `views.py` in my Contact app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse

def context(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ContactForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        subject = "Website Inquiry"
        body = {
            'first_name' : form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
            'last_name' : form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
            'email' : form.cleaned_data['email_address'],
            'message' : form.cleaned_data['message'],
         }
         message = "\n".join(body.values())

        try:
            send_mail(subject, message,'admin@example.com', ['admin@example.com'])
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return redirect("Posts:home")

  form = ContactForm()
  return render(request, "Posts/templates/contact/contact.html", {'form':form})
```

I have a templates folder in Posts app and inside it, I have 3 folders and put my contact.html in the contact folder(one of three).
[files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWyVq.png)

It is a [link](https://github.com/AylinNaebzadeh/Django-IUST-Application) to my project.

I have read about 10 posts which were about this problem but unfortunately, I could not solve it. I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your localhost. Did  you check to make sure your server is working from your browser?

Comment: sorry I did not understand. Do you mean I added it to my ALLOWED_HOST or not?@d6stringer

Comment: are the lines `form = ContactForm()` and 
`return render(request, "Posts/templates/contact/contact.html", {'form':form})` tabbed to be at the top level?

Comment: I have checked my project and it was working properly. But it does not work for this URL. Maybe I guess it can be because it can not find my contact.html file

Comment: yes sorry. They are in function but out of the ifs.@Zev

Comment: Share your whole traceback pls

Comment: The "post_detail" url in `Posts.urls` is being matched by your path "/contact/", try adding prefixes to the includes in your base urls.py to avoid conflicts between the included app urls

Comment: I have put a link to my error. Actually, it does not provide much info for this error I think.@Amin

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I was thinking 2 days to how to correct it. I had some errors too but they were easy to fix. But may you a bit explain why this conflict happen? I think there is not much relation between these two URLs but why server can not recognize it?@lain Shelvington

Comment: The url resolver loops over all urls 1 at a time until it finds a match, the include for `Path.urls` has an empty string which matches. Then the resolver follows the include and loops over all urls in `Post.urls` until it gets to "post_detail" which just has a slug argument which matches any string including "contact" and then the path is resolved. If not matches were found in `Posts.urls` then the resolver would have carried on and looped over `Contact.urls` until it found a match

Comment: Yes. Thanks again.@lain Shelvington

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is here:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('' , include('Posts.urls')),
   path('',include('Contact.urls')),
]
```

The second and the third URL point to the same path. Change it to:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('posts/', include('Posts.urls')),
   path('contact/', include('Contact.urls')),
]
```

And also in `urls.py` in `Contact` do this:

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.context, name="contact"),
]
```